# Android - Run code every some time. Workmanager? AlarmManager?

Tags: android, time, alarmmanager, android-workmanager

I have to execute some code every some time (users could set it, min once every 15 min).
The code to be executed do a download of some data from a website, check if there are changes (a compare of some string data) and if yes notify the user. So the execution of the code should be even if the app is closed\killed.
I read several guides and Q/A but I'm not sure which is the best way to do that. A WorkManager could fit it? An AlarmManager instead?

Thanks for the tips

Comment: As I wrote my periodic data uploader app, I was faced with a similar problem. As my app does not need exact periods, I decided for a Worker, that runs a service which shows forground notification. For you it seems to be better to use AlarmManager. Do not forget to show a foreground notification or Android will not start the Alarm. Alarms will also be triggered if device is in deep sleep, otherwise the AlarmClock settings will not wake you up. See also https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hope to find a good guide or example about it, first time I'm facing with that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to execute some code in a periodic way without being affected by the app's lifecycle.
I suggest trying the WorkManager component, as it supports periodic execution and actually uses AlarmMangaer.
Start by reading the formal documentation here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#schedule_periodic_work

Keep in mind that in doze mode the work may be deferred until maintenance time or going out of it, if the timing is important maybe you should use AlarmManager.

Good luck :)

Comment: I tried to use AlarmManager and seems that it works (I need to test more in different situations but right now without touch anything (star the AVD and wait) it repeat the code every some time). Now I need to implement a foreground service but no idea how to do it yet, I have to read and see some examples